# Loop within dask.array and gil lock

Tags: python, dask

Will the GIL lock significantly decrease performance of the following code?

The function over each block uses a python loop instead of numpy function. I have to use a python loop because of an external library.

Test code:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import dask.sharedict as sharedict
from itertools import product


def block_func(block):
    for i in range(len(block)):  # <--- the python loop ...
        block[i] += 1
    return block


def darr_func(x, name='test'):
    dsk = {}
    for idx in product(*map(range, x.numblocks)):
        dsk[(name,) + idx] = (block_func, (x.name,) + idx)
    dsk2 = sharedict.merge((name, dsk), x.dask)
    return da.Array(dsk2, name, x.chunks, x.dtype)


def main():
    n = 1000
    chunks = 100
    arr = np.arange(n*n).reshape(n, n)
    darr = da.from_array(arr, chunks=chunks)
    result = darr_func(darr)
    print(result.compute())


main()
```

If that is the case, can setting the context for scheduler help?
How to set context for a function over a dask array? I want to use the default dask scheduler for other operations over dask arrays.

From the wiki, I see ways to set scheduler for compute instead of a function:

```
# As a context manager
>>> with dask.set_options(get=dask.multiprocessing.get):
...     x.sum().compute()

# Set globally
>>> dask.set_options(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)
>>> x.sum().compute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python for loops do not release the GIL and so are hard to parallelize with threads.  In this case you have a few options

1. Use a project like Numba or Cython to write for-loop code that releases the GIL
2. Use a scheduler that splits the computation out to multiple process.  My personal recommendation is to use the dask.distributed scheduler locally, which can be done by running the following two lines:

   ```
   from dask.distributed import Client
   client = Client()
   ```

However as always you should profile your code and try a few things.  The advice given above depends on *many* factors.  For example Python for loops may not be an issue if the body of the loop releases the GIL.